# Unable to update CentOS6.6 due to 404

Tags: centos, yum, maintenance

For a long while I've had a scheduled call of 'yum upgrade' to keep my VPS healthy. Recently the update fails because no repositories can be found from the various mirrors.

http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6.6&arch=x86_64&repo=os
gives the list of mirror sites, but all of them return 404 (even from my personal computer).

Should I be able to access these mirror servers from a desktop browser? Has CentOS6.6 been discontinued??